# Declaring extra cigarettes when entering the EU

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, cdg

If I am travelling to the Schengen area on a short stay visa for 60 days, and I bring an extra 400 cigarettes from my home country for my own use and declare it to French customs, will they give me a fine or will they let me pass?

How much of a fine can I expect?

Answer (score 6):

> 400 cheap cigarettes from Home for personal use and declare it to CGD [French] customs, will they automatically slap a fine or let me through ?

You do **not** pay a fine if you delare items at customs that exceed the duty-free amounts.

When entering the EU the duty-free amount for cigarettes (or a combination of cigarettes, cigarillos, cigars and smoking tobacco) is 200 cigarettes (1 carton).

For the other 200 cigarettes, which you must declare, you must pay Excise Duty and VAT which differs from country to country.

An **unofficial** overview, dated 2022-05-31, can be seen here:

- [Cigarette Taxes in the EU 2022 European Cigarette and Tobacco Tax Map](https://taxfoundation.org/cigarette-tax-europe-2022/)

  - assume that the shown values can change at any time!

For France, it presently shows for 20 cigarettes €8.57 Total Tax:

- €6.88 Excise Duty
- €1.69 VAT

That would then be €85.70 for 200 cigarettes.

[image]

Comment: (Comment from OP) Any possibility the VAT/Duty will be waived ? or are they very 'by the book'

Comment: For Tobacco and Alcohol assume that it is very much 'by the book'.

Comment: And also assume that if found and not declared the cigarettes will be taken from you and you will be fined.